# Assign a value to java class, but is not returning value

Tags: java, swing

So I have a student class.

I have a Jlist and try to add a student object. I set dob value.

Everything runs fine no issue. When I retrive sout "student" it returns all other values, but not Dob. 
When I call student.getDob() in fact it returns, means it's assigned.

Don't know why it doesn't retrieve in student as an object. I am thinking maybe there is a bug in netbeans.

Any help?

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    // Create an instance of student
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFName(firstNameField.getText());
    student.setLName(lastNameField.getText());
    student.setDob(dateOfBirthField.getText());
    student.setGender((String) genderComboBox.getSelectedItem());
    System.out.println(student.getDob());

    // Add student to the list
    ListModel lModel = jList1.getModel();
    DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
    int total = lModel.getSize();
    for (int x = 0; x < total; x++) {
        dlm.addElement(lModel.getElementAt(x));
    }
    dlm.addElement(student);
    jList1.setModel(dlm);
    //Clearing the text fields for the next entry
    firstNameField.setText("");
    lastNameField.setText("");
    dateOfBirthField.setText("");
    genderComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);}
}
```

Student Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Date;

public class Student {

     private String id;


    private String fName;


    private String lName;

    private String gender;

    private String dob;

    private ArrayList<Address> addresses;

    private Instructor instructor;


    private ArrayList<Courses> courses;


    public Student () {
    }


    public ArrayList<Address> getAddresses () {
        return addresses;
    }


    public void setAddresses (ArrayList<Address> val) {
        this.addresses = val;
    }


    public ArrayList<Courses> getCourses () {
        return courses;
    }


    public void setCourses (ArrayList<Courses> val) {
        this.courses = val;
    }


    public String getDob () {
        return dob;
    }


    public void setDob (String val) {
        this.dob = val;
    }


    public String getFName () {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setFName (String val) {
        this.fName = val;
    }


    public String getGender () {
        return gender;
    }


    public void setGender (String val) {
        this.gender = val;
    }


    public String getId () {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId (String val) {
        this.id = val;
    }


    public Instructor getInstructor () {
        return instructor;
    }

    public void setInstructor (Instructor val) {
        this.instructor = val;
    }

    public String getLName () {
        return lName;
    }


    public void setLName (String val) {
        this.lName = val;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
    return getFName()+" "+getLName()+" "+getGender();
    } 
}
```

Comment: The bug is in your code of course. Look at your Student.toString() method. given its code, it should be clear why the dob is not printed when you print a student. NetBeans, BTW, is an IDE. It doesn't run your code. The JVM runs your code. It's a common trap to think that a bug is in someone else's code, and I've fallen into this trap more than once. But in 99.999% of the cases, especially if you're a newbie, it's not. Most of the code from someone else that you use is also used by millions of programs and developers, and is much better tested and debugged than your own.

Comment: I suggest - debug your code to identify where `dob` variable loosing its value.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it with deep debugging. In the student class Dob was not stringified. Added getDob() at the end.

```
@Override
    public String toString(){
    return getFName()+" "+getLName()+" "+getGender()+" "+getDob(); 
    }
```